# Purging audit records - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit

At the end of each financial year, audit team asks for audit records for samples dates in a year as per their methodology and ideally we are supposed to provide them. (Say, give them list of schemas dropped in a particular month or modifications made for a schema in a month)

Now, im in a situation I need to save the audit data for one complete year, is there anyway to purge the audit data on a monthly basis and at the same time provide the necessary info by the end of the year. The reason I need to purge is because of the audit file size which grows to a huge size.

What choices do I have? I do not have license to Oracle Audit Vault as well.

Comment: Have a look for this work around http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57752/oracle-sys-auditing-with-audit-trail-to-db?rq=1

Comment: you don't need audit vault.  You just need to take a look at the features provided by the package dbms_audit_mgmt.  If you don't have the disk space to keep a years worth of data in the databases audit table (sys.aud$) then where are you going to keep it outside of the database?

Answer (score 2):

[Archiving the Database Audit Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG0624)

[Scheduling an Automatic Purge Job for the Audit Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG465)

[Manually Purging the Audit Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG472)

Basically you copy the audit trail to another table, e.g:

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT ... FROM SYS.AUD$ ...;
INSERT INTO table SELECT ... FROM SYS.FGA_LOG$ ...;
```

You can just export and drop these tables, then import them when you need to access audit records.

Then you set the last archive timestamp, e.g:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.SET_LAST_ARCHIVE_TIMESTAMP(
   AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE     =>  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD,
   LAST_ARCHIVE_TIME    =>  '2009-05-28 06:30:00.00'   
   RAC_INSTANCE_NUMBER  =>  0 );
END;
/
```

Finally you initialize cleanup and schedule a purge or run it manually:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.INIT_CLEANUP(
  AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE            => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD,
  DEFAULT_CLEANUP_INTERVAL    => 12 );
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CREATE_PURGE_JOB (
   AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE            => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD, 
   AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE_INTERVAL  => 12,
   AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE_NAME      => 'Standard_Audit_Trail_PJ',
   USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP     => TRUE );
END;
/
```

Manual:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL(
   AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE           =>  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD,
   USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP    =>  TRUE );
END;
/
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use dbms job to purge? A simple remove directly from the file system won't do the job?